# How to store keycode's into a array and execute them?

Tags: c#, arrays, keycode

I'm wondering if it's possible to store keyboard input history into a array and execute them at a later time? Basically I have a 3D grid game and a character moving around the grid. I want the user to enter all the movement instructions via right down left up keys while the player remains still, and once I press enter the player will begin to execute each instruction that is stored into the array.
any suggestions?

Comment: Yes - follow exactly what you have in the post and it should work. What exact problem you have implementing it?

Comment: sorry I wasnt very clear. Ive been looking around the API and couldnt find exactly what i need. like which function should i call to execute each instruction when im looping through the array?

Comment: Store entries in a List<string> collection.  Use the collection as a FIFO.  Add new entries at end of list.  Remove entries at item zero.  You can also use a StringBuilder which is a type of List<string>.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Training : MonoBehaviour {

public List<KeyCode> previousActions;

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){
        Debug.Log("Do something");
        previousActions.Add(KeyCode.A);
    }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)){
        Debug.Log("Do something else");
        previousActions.Add(KeyCode.S);
    //---Check the list--//
    }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)){
        Debug.Log("Check the list");
        for(int i = 0;i < previousActions.Count;i++){
            Debug.Log(previousActions[i]);
        }
    }
}
```